# how to access the data object from the function using parameter passed as object name

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vuex

I want to access the data object from the methods and modify the values inside the data object, the name of the object I want to access comes from the function parameter

template

```
<tbody>
   <td>B</td>
   <td>High Kick Fwd</td>
   <td>{{kal.totalPoints}}</td>
   <template v-for="elements in kal">
      <td
      v-for="item in elements"
      :key="elements[item]"
      @click="universalfunction(kal)" // passing the object 
      :class="{red:item.mistake,green:!item.mistake}"
      class="workingElemments"
      >{{item.Marks}}</td>
   </template>
   <td>{{parseFloat(kal.markObtain).toFixed(2)}}</td>
</tbody>
```

```
data: function() {
    return {
        kal: {
            elements: {
            below90: { mistake: false, Marks: 0.4 },
            bodyPosition: { mistake: false, Marks: 0.2 },
            toeFlex: { mistake: false, Marks: 0.1 },
            Hezitation: { mistake: false, Marks: 0.1 }
        },
        totalPoints: 1,
        markObtain: 1.0
    }
}
```

```
universalfunction: function(pObject) {
    this.pObject.elements.mistake = true; //error: cannot access the elements of undefined 
}
```

what I want is the function should access the data object according to the parameter name and modify the original object

Comment: Remove `this`  .

Answer (score 0):

`pObject` isn't a property on the `this` object - it's been passed as a parameter to the `universalfunction` function.

```
universalfunction: function(pObject) {
    this.pObject.elements.mistake = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few assumptions about what you're trying to achieve but I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    kal: {
      elements: {
        below90: {
          mistake: false,
          Marks: 0.4
        },
        bodyPosition: {
          mistake: false,
          Marks: 0.2
        },
        toeFlex: {
          mistake: false,
          Marks: 0.1
        },
        Hezitation: {
          mistake: false,
          Marks: 0.1
        }
      },
      totalPoints: 1,
      markObtain: 1.0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    universalFunction (item) {
      item.mistake = !item.mistake;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.workingElements {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>High Kick Fwd</td>
        <td>{{ kal.totalPoints }}</td>
        <td
          v-for="(item, propertyName) in kal.elements"
          :key="propertyName"
          :class="item.mistake ? 'red': 'green'"
          class="workingElements"
          @click="universalFunction(item)"
        >
          {{item.Marks}}
        </td>
        <td>{{ kal.markObtain.toFixed(2) }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I've removed one of the loops as it didn't seem to make sense with the data you had. Looping over the outer object was causing two unnecessary empty cells to be created in the table. Instead I'm just looping over the `elements` and passing the relevant item to the method when it's clicked.

An alternative would be to pass the name using `@click="universalFunction(propertyName)"` (where I've declared `propertyName` in my `v-for`) and then have the method as:

```js
universalFunction (name) {
  this.kal.elements[name].mistake = true;
}
```

Personally I would recommend using an array rather than an object to store the `elements`.